# Android recyclerview won't update on Android Nougat

Tags: android, json, android-volley

Basicly my code will fetch certain rows from a database using php, JSON and Android-Volley, then it will parse and display the data as a button and a textview in a recyclerview.
The code is working perfectly fine on android 6, but after upgrading my phone to android 7 the recyclerview code won't disply the results.
I made sure that the php is working and the android function that retrieves the rows is also working, only the recyclerview will not display the rows.
here is my code for retreiving the rows:

```
private void loadTickets()
    {
        ArrayList<Workorder> wo = new ArrayList<Workorder>();
        GetWorkordersTask bt = new GetWorkordersTask(MyWorkorders.this, UserID);
        wo = bt.getworkorders();//this works find and i know the number of rows retrieved.
        adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(wo);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

now my adapter code looks like this:

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder>  {


ArrayList<Workorder> arrayList=new ArrayList<>();
public RecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<Workorder> arrayList)
{
    this.arrayList=arrayList;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.workorder_item,parent,false);
    MyViewHolder myViewHolder=new MyViewHolder(view);
    return myViewHolder;

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.WO_VIEW.setText(arrayList.get(position).getWo_no());
    holder.WO_USER.setText(arrayList.get(position).getWo_user());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return arrayList.size();
}



public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    private final Context context;
    Button WO_VIEW;
    TextView WO_USER;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        WO_VIEW=(Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnview);
        WO_USER=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtusername);
        WO_VIEW.setOnClickListener(this);
        context = itemView.getContext();
    }

}
```

and to be fair, i copied some of the code from a youtube video (cant remember the channel) so changes were made to make it work the way i want.

Comment: Did you find any solutions?

Comment: i rewrote the entire code from scratch and it started working, i don't have any explanation :)

Comment: this is driving me nuts ...lol